# How to get details for hardware with "This device is not working" message

Tags: 18.04, additional-drivers

How do you get detailed information about hardware displayed in the GUI as not working?

When I go to `Software & Updates` -> `Additional Drivers` -> `Intel Corporation: Unknown`, I see the message `This device is not working`.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2mBf.png)

```
Intel Corporation: Unknown
This device is not working.
[ ] Using iwlwifi driver backport in DKMS format from backport-iwlwifi-dkms (open source) *grayed out*
[ ] Continue using a manually installed driver
[x] Do not use the deivce *grayed out*
```

When I try to choose the only non-grayed out option (Continue using a manaully installed driver). I'm unable to click Apply Changes.

I have an Intel AX200 card installed. Both WiFi and Bluetooth are working.

```
uname -a
Linux ubuntu-1804-laptop 5.3.0-41-generic #33~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 17 12:51:52 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Is your Intel wireless actually working as expected? Does it see networks, connect and load internet pages? If so, I suggest that you ignore *Additional Drivers* as this is likely a bug.

Comment: Both WiFi and Bluetooth are working.

Comment: Awesome! You're all set then.

Comment: Is there a current launchpad bug report for this issue?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs Not that I am aware of. Please search for and, if needed, start one.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1859308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known bug is logged with Launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1859308

Comment: Any solution of this issue other then reinstalling ubuntu?